# Get Skim annotation types in AppleScript as string

Tags: applescript

I have encountered a somewhat odd problem while scripting the Mac PDF viewer app Skim. I am attempting to format Skim annotations for export. I have a handler that formats things differently based on the various annotation types (text note, highlight note, anchored note, underline note, strike thru note). I don't want to call to Skim in my various handlers, so I am trying to pass the annotation type as a string (not as a constant), but I am coming across an odd error when running the script from the Terminal. Here is a simple example of the problem:

If I save a script with this code:

`tell application "Skim" to return type of (note 1 of front document) as string`

and I run it from the AppleScript editor, I get a Result like `"highlight note"`. If, however, I run that script from Terminal (e.g. `osascript test.scpt`), I get this result: 

`«constant ****NHil»`

So, when I try to run `if, then` checks for annotation types, my handlers work when run from the Editor, but fail when run from the Terminal (the only way I want to run them). For example, this statement returns `true` in the Editor: `return "highlight note" = («constant ****NHil» as string)` but `false` from the Terminal.

So, my question: How can I deal with Skim annotation types as strings in AppleScript when running a script from the Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant coercion will fail, because `osascript` don't load the terminology just to run a compiled script.

First solution: save the applescript as "**text**" format

```
osascript test.applescript
```

-

Second solution (without script file):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Skim" to (type of note 1 of front document) as text'
```

-

Third solution (this appleScript):

`run script "tell application \"Skim\" to (type of note 1 of front document) as text"`

-

Fourth solution (this appleScript):

```
tell application "Skim" to tell (get type of note 1 of front document)
    if it = text note then return "text note"
    if it = anchored note then return "anchored note"
    if it = circle note then return "circle note"
    if it = highlight note then return "highlight note"
    if it = underline note then return "underline note"
    if it = strike out note then return "strike out note"
    if it = line note then return "line note"
    if it = freehand note then return "freehand note"
end tell
```

Comment: This is wonderful and I've used the uncompiled .applescript solution. Thank you.